# Rails group and count distinct records

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database of customer credit cards (not full numbers, just CC type and if they passed validation), and I'm trying to count the number of each type of card (Visa, Amex, etc).

The type of card is stored as `type` in the `Cards` table.

I've tried this: `Card.count(:type).distinct` but get an `undefined method 'distinct'` error.

Ultimately trying to return an array of each card type and how many of that type are in the table.

I'm running Rails 4.0.1 and Ruby 2.0.0 on a Postgres database.

Comment: Try `Card.count('distinct type')`

Comment: @vinodadhikary's comment should be the answer IMO

Comment: @engineerDave That just tells me the number of card types (ie. 3). Claudio's answer gives me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing a quick review to [api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html) maybe this example:

```
Person.group(:city).count
```

is what you need

So, it should be something like:

```
Card.group(:type).count
```

Answer (score 0):

```
card_types = Card.all.select("distinct type").map(&:type)    
card_types.each do |ctype| 
  puts "There were #{Card.where(:type => ctype).count} cards of the '#{ctype}' type"
end
```

This might be what you're looking for. There are "tighter" ways to implement this of course, however.

By the way, 'type' is reserved in rails and is not an allowed column name

Answer (score 0):

Try:- Card.count(:group=> :type)